# How to get the value of an element using javascript in Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, robotframework, return-value

I am trying to get the value of an input using javascript. The reason is because is not present in the HTML.
I want to get the text "https://wwww.urldeprueba.com".

[image]

Since the value is not in the html I executed this in the console to get the text of the element

[image]

Now, I am trying to execute the same statement in Robot Framework:

```
${test} = Execute Javascript return (document.querySelector('#configurations\\\\ text-right > form > div > div > div:nth-child(29) > input').value)
Log ${test}
```

But I got,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robot framework's [selenium library](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Value) provides you this functionality.

you can grab this value simply doing -

```
${ASPURL}=    Get Value    xpath://input[@ng-model='ASPUrl']
```